# Can Grad CAM feature maps be used for Training?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, gradient-descent, architecture, pytorch

I am trying to recreate the architecture of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.03058.pdf

Can someone help me in explaining how are the feature maps coming out of the output of GradCam used in the following conv layers?